# Shows "unable to locate package unzip" error

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 server , shows

```
E:unable to locate the package unzip
```

the above error is also shown, if I try to install packages also. Can any one help me out to get out from this error.

Comment: provide the complete error report from pastebin . we can have a look then .

Comment: Please also specify what packages you try to install. Standard (essential) compression utilities in Ubuntu are **gzip**/**gunzip** not unzip.

Comment: @Takkat `unzip` is also a standard compression utility, provided by the package of the same name. It decompresses `.zip` files (whereas `gunzip` decompresses `.gz` files). **user76114**: Please edit your question to provide the information imwrng requested, and also the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @EliahKagan: For DEB packages zip is **not standard**. As gzip is an **essential** package the OP should definitely not see this error on "installing packages". We won't find out as this Q looks a bit abandoned to me.

Comment: @Takkat The OP certainly *would* see this error on "installing packages" if the packages being installed include `unzip` or [anything that depends on it](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091466/). Since the Ubuntu Server system is now installed, the problem before us is to figure out why this error is happening when installing other software on the system.

Comment: @LordofTime [`unzip`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/unzip) is [in main](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091475/).

Answer (score 41):

Type `sudo apt-get update` to get the lists updated.

If its the first time you are running this command, it would download something like 20 MB of data.

Then type `sudo apt-get upgrade` to install the updates, if you want.

You can avoid this step, if you want to install updates later.

After first step finishes successfully, you should be able to install the package unzip by typing `sudo apt-get install unzip`.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem on a fresh Rack space install of 12.04.  The solution:

```
sudo apt-get install zip -y
```

This installed both zip and unzip.

Comment: can you please help me with what does -y means with sudo?

Comment: got it @Sam it means yes... thanks

Comment: For future readers, it doesn't just mean "yes", it means "assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively." See https://superuser.com/a/1436171/64024